# jQuery AJAX GET response

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am using jQuery ajax method to get response from my server. Here's my code:

```
function getText(id){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/myurl/' + id + '/edit.js',
        data: {'id': id},
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```

I am using ruby on rails, and on my rails controller, I am sending some text as json response. When I check in the firebug, the data is returned correctly. But I don't get anything with the **alert(data);** that I have called upon success. Can anyone tell me what's wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: You're receiving plain text as a response?

Comment: ya, actually, initially, i sent myobj.content as json response. Later, I sent myobj as json, and was able to access the required parameter as data.myobj.content. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the alert does it same something like Object object? It should as the data is now a JavaScript object. If you want to see your data, look at the properties, e.g. `alert(data.someProperty)`.

Answer (score 2):

`dataType: 'json'` specifies that you are receiving json data from the Ajax call. You're treating that `data` as if it were plain text. If you are, in fact, receiving plain text, then you need to set `dataType: 'text'`. If you're receiving HTML, then specify `dataType: 'html'`